# Modifying array on table

Tags: php, arrays

i'm having trouble on data placement, so here is the problem, hope you guys can help me on this

i have put this data on array:

what i have been tried:

```
        $a = array();
        $b = array();
        $c = array();

        for($itung=0; $itung < $j; $itung++){
            if($a[$itung][0] != '--'){
                $count_a += 1;
            }else{
                $count_a += 0;
            }

            if($count_a == 0){
                $table .= '<tr>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.($itung+1).'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$a[$itung][2].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">123</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$a[$itung][0].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$a[$itung][1].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$a[$itung][3].'</td>';
                $count_a++;
            }else{
                $table .= '<tr>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.($itung+1).'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$a[$itung][2].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">123</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$a[$itung][0].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$a[$itung][1].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$a[$itung][3].'</td>';
                $count_a += 0;
            }

            if($b[$itung][0] != '--'){
                $count_b += 1;
            }else{
                $count_b += 0;
            }

            if($count_a > 0 || $count_b > 0){
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$b[$itung][0].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$b[$itung][1].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$b[$itung][3].'</td>'; 

            }else{
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$b[$itung][0].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$b[$itung][1].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$b[$itung][3].'</td>'; 
            }

            if($c[$itung][0] != '--'){
                $count_c += 1;
            }else{
                $count_c += 0;
            }

            if($count_a > 0 || $count_b > 0 || $count_c > 0){
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$c[$itung][0].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$c[$itung][1].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$c[$itung][3].'</td>'; 
                if($c[$itung][0] != '--'){
                    $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">1</td>'; 
                }else{
                    $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">0</td>'; 
                }

                $count_a = 0;
                $count_b = 0;
                $count_c = 0;
            }else{
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$c[$itung][0].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$c[$itung][1].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td class="tg-s6z2">'.$c[$itung][3].'</td>'; 

                $count_a = 0;
                $count_b = 0;
                $count_c = 0;
            }

        }
```

sample :

```
| col a | col b | col c |
|  1    |  --  |   --   |
|  1    |  --  |   --   |
|  --   |   1  |   --   |
|  1    |  --  |   --   |
|  --   |  --  |   1   |
```

what i'm expect : (result)

```
| col a | col b | col c |
|  1    |   --  |  --  |
|  1    | **1** |  --  |
|**1**  | *--*  |  --  |
| *--*  | *--*  |**1** |
```

so if col a have data, the check on col b, if col b has data then col b go up to the same row with col a, so as the col c

sorry for my bad english, hope you guys can understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate logic and template. I mean first loop through your data, copying it to a new array according to your logic. Then you can easily build html table from new, simpler data.

From I understand form your example, you could write something like this:

```
$a = array(/*some data*/);
$b = array(/*some data*/);
$c = array(/*some data*/);

$out = array();
$j = 0; //index of output array - table row
for($i = 0; $i<count($a); i++) {
    if($a[i] == 1) {
        $out[j][0] = $a[i];
        if($b[$i+1] == 1) {
            $out[j][1] = $b[$i+1];
        }
        $j++;
    } else {
        if($c[$i] == 1) {
            $out[j][2] = $c[$i];
        }
        $j++;
    }
}

buildTable($out); //now you can build nice html array, 
                // or send data in json to some API
                // e.g. to build this table dynamically with javascript
```

Comment: thank for replying, i got an idea from your answer that i should make an empty array to contain the others, thanks